# How are the SO Python chat room owners chosen?

Tags: discussion, chat

I know there is a process when it comes to Stack Overflow [moderator elections](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6), with votes, questions, and so on, ensuring a person that knows the rules well and has the qualifications for the job is elected. There are some requirements, like badges, and the elections last several days. For example:

> Our general criteria for moderators are as follows:
>
> - patient and fair
> - leads by example
> - shows respect for their fellow community members in their actions and    words
> - open to some light but firm moderation to keep the community on track    and resolve (hopefully) uncommon disputes and exceptions

and:

> For the Stack Overflow election, an eligible candidate for the
>   election must have all of the following badges:
>
> - Civic Duty
> - Strunk & White
> - Deputy
> - Convention

---

What is the process for [SO Python chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) room owner elections (are there actually elections)? By whom are they chosen and based on what criteria? I understand the criteria aren't as strict, since they have fewer responsibilities, but what are they? What are the minimum requirements a user must have to become a room owner, and what process is followed?

Comment: to become an owner of a chat room, a user must have an account and be added to the list of room owners by another person on that list (this can even happen before they have the necessary reputation to enter chat, as a way to bypass that restriction, I believe). each chat room seems to be fairly independent.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that moderation is quite hands-off when it comes to chat rooms. A room with no active room owners will [eventually be appointed a new one automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80208/189583). In exceptional circumstances, a room owner may be [removed by moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93116/189583) , although I have only found a single public instance of this. Other than this, room ownership appears to be entirely up to the existing room owners.

The remainder of my post applies specifically to the Python room. Other rooms may have completely different processes.

> What is the process for SO Python chat room owner elections (are there actually elections)?

There aren't *public* elections, no.

> By whom are they chosen...

On our private off-site RO message board, an RO proposes a community member for room ownership. There is a brief 1-2 day period of discussion, and if general consensus is achieved, we extend an offer to the user.

> and based on what criteria?

No formal list of prerequisite qualities exist, but typical discussion points are:

- is the user frequently active in here?
- Do they actually know Python?
- Will they nurture the kind of community we are trying to cultivate?
- How likely are they to go crazy and de-RO everyone but themselves?

AFAIK we have never had to revoke room ownership on account of bad behavior, so there's no precedent for what kind of conduct would require such a response. We've only ever revoked ownership for ROs that have been idle for many months, or users that voluntarily stepped down.

This is an evolving process; we care about how the public views us, and we don't want anyone to feel like they're being oppressed. To that effect, we have regular room meetings (the next one being [August 19th 15:00 UTC](http://sopython.com/transcript/6/summer-2015-general-meeting/)) where anyone has the floor to bring up business they feel is important.

Comment: Could you provide a few more details on what type of community you need the new RO to cultivate?

Comment: Probably the same thing every other room wants - a safe space for people to ask constructive questions, and a place for regulars to hang out that is less strict than the main site.

Comment: Would the ["general criteria"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) be a useful addition and would ROs be willing to include them both in chatroom description and their actions?